# md-sidenav full height + lack of animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I would like to have a toolbar at the top with a full height sidebar on the left fixed when the screen is big - toolbar should start from the sidenav. The right side only should be scrollable. If the screen is smaller, the sidebar should hide, and to show it, the user should click the button on the toolbar which should be 100% width.

Currently, my sidenav is not full height, as a result, my toolbar is 100% width. I tried to use flex to acheive it but I have done something wrong.

I didn't implement a controller to manage showing the menu button yet, but I assume my problem is independent from it.

Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.5/angular-material.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-cloak>

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl" layout="column" flex>
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" arial-label="menu">
                <md-icon md-font-icon="fa-ellipsis-h" class="fa fa-2x"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <h2>test</h2>
            <span flex=""></span>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" arial-label="favourite">
                <md-icon md-font-icon="fa-star" class="fa fa-2x"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

<section layout="row" flex >
        <md-sidenav style="max-width:320px;" layout="column"
                class="md-sidenav-left"
                md-component-id="left"
                md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')"
                md-whiteframe="4"
                flex>
            <md-toolbar>
                <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">menu</h1>
            </md-toolbar>
            <md-content layout-padding>
                <p>
                    This sidenav is locked open on your device. To go back to the default behavior,
                    narrow your display.
                </p>
            </md-content>
        </md-sidenav>

        <md-content flex class="md-padding">
        Some content !!
    </md-content>
</section>

</div>
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.11.2 used here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.5/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);
    app.controller('mainCtrl', function () {

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Out this soultion. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/mPWrvB

Let me know if anything is missing. I used `md-button` in the `toolbar`. You can easliy replace it with `md-icon`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [nextt1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3428668/nextt1) who solution was very close to this I wanted to acheive, I finally got it.

```
here is my solution:
```

http://codepen.io/AgilePlayers/pen/eZvBLB

Comment: You could have just edited my answer and accept that. but anyways happy to help.

Comment: You're right. The answer has been accepted. Thanks one more time for your help!

Comment: No problem at all. :)